# updating value by extension method without return

Tags: c#, extension-methods

now I use like this;

```
c1 = c1.AddItem(d1);

public static T AddItem<T, TItem>(this T entity, TItem item) where T : BaseClass<T>
{
    //somecode
    return entity; 
}
```

but I want to be able to change value without return;

```
c1.AddItem(d1);

public static void AddItem<T, TItem>(this T entity, TItem item) where T : BaseClass<T>
{
    //somecode 
}
```

any idea how to make this work?

FULL CODE

```
public class C : BaseClass<C>
{
    public virtual int CId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<D> DList { get; set; }

    public C()
    {
        DList = new List<D>();
    }
}



    public static T AddItem<T, TItem>(this T entity, TItem item) where T : BaseClass<T>
    {
        var propertyList = item.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();

        var prop = propertyList.Find(c => c.PropertyType == typeof(T));

        if (propertyList.Any(c => c.PropertyType == typeof(T)))
        {
            propertyList.Find(c => c.PropertyType == typeof(T)).SetValue(item, entity);
        }
        else
        {
            ((IList<T>)propertyList.Find(c => c.PropertyType == typeof(IList<T>)).GetValue(item)).Add(entity);
        }

        var a = ((IList<TItem>)entity.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().Find(c => c.PropertyType == typeof(IList<TItem>)).GetValue(entity));
        if (a.GetType().Name == "PersistentGenericBag`1")
        {
            entity = entity.Load(x => (IList<TItem>)x.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().Find(c => c.PropertyType == typeof(IList<TItem>)).GetValue(x));
            a = ((IList<TItem>)entity.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().Find(c => c.PropertyType == typeof(IList<TItem>)).GetValue(entity));
        }

        a.Add(item);

        entity.Save();

        return entity;
    }


    public static T Load<T, TItem>(this T entity, Func<T, IList<TItem>> listGetter) where T : class
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper<T>.OpenSession())
        {
            T reAttached = session.Merge<T>(entity);
            NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.Initialize(listGetter.Invoke(reAttached));

            return reAttached;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to re-assign the "entity" reference? You can declare it as an 'out' parameter.

Comment: What is the problem with what you have tried?

Comment: @sstan not sexy enough

Comment: [C# Extension Methods MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The way you wrote it will work....

Comment: @Andrew I wish but It doesn't

Comment: What happens? can you post the code you used in the method?

Comment: Its long code but I will demonstrate with simpler code. I tested result same with this one too. added in quesiton

Comment: Your sample code just makes everything more confusing.  Of course you can't change a string, it's immutable.  Is this question simply about not understanding how immutable objects work?

Comment: @stann yeah you are right, which means my class is immutable too?

Comment: Could you show what kind of objects are you trying to modify? Strings are immutable... but the code you write should work with any other non-value type

Comment: @ blacai, @stann I added my class in question too

Comment: @sstan, he tries to change passed reference. nothing with immutability here

Comment: I added whole code in question.

Comment: The only thing missing now is clearly stating the expected result, and what you are currently getting instead.  And if you are getting an exception of some sort, make sure to post it with full details.

Comment: Can you also show the code for `entity.Load()`?

Comment: @Ben Robinson: `T` is restricted with `where T : BaseClass<T>`.  So the `Load` method must be defined inside the `BaseClass` class, which is not shown.  In any case, it does look like that line is the problem.  And I'm sure that when OP posts the contents of the `Load` method, the problem will become very obvious.

Comment: @stann I added load too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be caused by this line:

```
entity = entity.Load(x => (IList<TItem>)x.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().Find(c => c.PropertyType == typeof(IList<TItem>)).GetValue(x));
```

Now that you have posted the contents of the `Load` method, we can see that it, in turn, calls:

```
T reAttached = session.Merge<T>(entity);
// ...
return reAttached;
```

My knowledge of Hibernate is limited, but chances are good that, if not always, at least sometimes, the call to `Merge` will return a reference to a different object instance from what is passed in.

This has the cascading effect that, in your extension method, the local variable `entity` gets reassigned to a completely new object.  Because the `entity` reference variable is a *copy* of the `c1` reference variable (and not a reference to it), when it gets reassigned, the change is not reflected in the `c1` variable.  Your `c1` variable effectively still points to the original `entity` instance *before* it got changed by the call to `BaseClass.Load()`.

Basically, as others have already stated, to code an extension method that doesn't need to return an `entity` reference, you have to limit yourself to changing the *state* of the `entity` object through its methods/properties.  You can't actually change the object reference completely, because this will never be reflected outside the method call.

In your case, it looks like you should stick with your original extension method that returns the `entity` reference.

---

Relevant reading: [Parameter passing in C#](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html)

In particular, the section **Sidenote: what is the difference between passing a value object by reference and a reference object by value?** applies to what is happening here.

Comment: I will investigate that Merge part. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, with other class-types your code should work.

```
public class BaseClass<TItem>
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        ItemList = new List<TItem>();
    }
    public List<TItem> ItemList { get; set; }
}

public static void AddItem<T, TItem>(this T entity, TItem item)
    where T :BaseClass<TItem>
{
    //somecode 
    entity.ItemList.Add(item);
}


public class TItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BaseClass<TItem> myEntity = new BaseClass<TItem>();
    TItem newItem = new TItem();
    newItem.Name = "Hi";
    myEntity.AddItem(newItem);
}
```